# Editing MP4 video

Tags: edit-mode

I'm looking for a video showing how to edit MP4 video clips. For instance I'd like to take this clip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAhvQoLpvsM and remove the text below the PlayStation symbol, but keep everything else the same. Is this possible with Blender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the Import Image As Planes Addon.

Align the camera to the top view. Change its Lens to Orthographic. Change its resolution to match the movie resolution.

Enable the World Environment light.

Use the menu add to insert the video using Add > Mesh > Images as planes. Scale it to fit the camera size. Change the timeline duration to match the movie duration. Change its shading to Shadeless.

Insert a black image using Images as planes also. Drag it a little up. Move it until it covers the text. Change its shading to Shadeless.

With the black plane still selected move the timeline to the point the text appear and hit  <kbd>I</kbd>  to make a key frame. Move the timeline one frame back, move the black plane outside the camera view and hit  <kbd>I</kbd>  again. this will make the black plane to appear when the text appears.

Set the Output to FFmpeg video. The encoding presets choose H.264 in mp4.

Render the animation.

See the image below.

[image]